# Conditional expectation of X given X > 1

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

Let X ~ Exp(λ). How would we find E(X|X > 1).

I know that the E(X|X > 1) = $\int x P(X | X > 1)$ = $\int x \frac{P(X = x \space and \space X>1)}{P(X > 1)}$

But im not sure how to evaluate the fraction.

Thanks!

Comment: X is a continuous random variable so you need to use integrals, not sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Exponential distribution is continuous.

\begin{align} E[X|X>1] &= \int_1^\infty x \frac{\lambda \exp(-\lambda x)}{\exp(-\lambda )} \, dx \\
&=\int_1^\infty x \lambda \exp(-\lambda (x-1)) \, dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty (y+1) \lambda\exp(-\lambda y) \, dy\\
&= \int_0^\infty \lambda\exp(-\lambda y) \, dy + \int_0^\infty y \lambda \exp(-\lambda y) \, dy \\
&= 1+E[X]\end{align}

This is known as memoryless property of exponential distribution.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to get the first equality, please?

Comment: The denominator is just $P(X>1)$, I am just reweighting the density function.

Comment: So you are "creating" the new density $f_{X|X>1}(x)$?

Comment: yup, I did that.

Comment: How did you derive the density $f_{X|X>1}(x)$? Thanks

Comment: if $x>1$, $f_{X|X>1}(x) = \frac{f_X(x)}{P(X > 1)} $

Comment: I'm still unsure how you can get the numerator (and how you broke it up into cases). I'm having confusion in my linked question which is finding this

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying for is: $~\mathsf E(X\mid X>1) ~{=
\dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X>1})}{\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X>1})} \\= \dfrac{\int_1^\infty \lambda x e^{-\lambda d x}\mathsf d x}{\int_1^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda d x}\mathsf d x}\\~~\vdots\\=1+\lambda^{-1}}$

Comment: Can you explain how you got the first assignment?

Comment: By the definition of conditioning expectation on an event.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a simpler approach is to note that $$E(X\mid X\gt1)=1+E(X)$$

since the exponential distribution is memoryless.

As Vincent pointed out, the exponential distribution is continuous so you should be integrating.

We have $$E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have that the expectation is $$\mathbb{E}[X|X>1]=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>a|X>1)da=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>a, X>1)}{\mathbb{P}( X>1)}da=\frac{1}{e^{-\lambda}}(\int_{0}^{1}\mathbb{P}(X>1)da+\int_{1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>a)da)=\frac{1}{e^{-\lambda}}([ae ^{-\lambda}]^1_0+[\frac{e^{-\lambda a}}{\lambda}]^{\infty}_1)=\frac{1}{e^{-\lambda}}(e^{-\lambda}+\frac{e^{-\lambda a}}{\lambda})=1+\frac{1}{\lambda}$$