# Conditional expectation $E[\log(1+X)∣X>a]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

How can I compute this conditional expectation given I only have access to $P(X>t)$?

I have been looking into the literature for quite sometime and have not seen something similar.

Please help!!
Thank you

Comment: Is $t$ fixed?..

Comment: Yes $t$ is a constant

Comment: You cannot compute this quantity based on the tail at a fixed $t$ !

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by fixed t, it is an arbitrary variable that takes on values between $0$ and $\infty$

Comment: You already asked this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345723/conditional-expectation-e-log1x-mid-xt

Please do not ask duplicate questions.